# Trying to remove delay

Tags: javascript, video

All I am doing here is trying to remove the delay.

The YouTube video (aka iframe) doesn't get created until after `createPlayer(args)` is called on line 140. Since it is part of the click handler that means it gets created after the click. There is a delay happening as the video is fetched and loaded.

[image]

How would this be fixed in the code so that there is not a delay?

**To reproduce**: Click **Run**, then the play image, do it repeatedly to see the delay.

After clicking the the play image, it doesn't go straight to the video, there's a delay that occurs that can be clearly seen.

How would I remove that delay?

Click **Run**, not update to test Jsitor code: https://jsitor.com/W0Iu1msGS

You can make edits to the JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/w2Lphczf/

The delay appears in both.

```
    const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
        const config = {};
    
        function show(el) {
            el.classList.remove("hide");
        }
    
        function hide(el) {
            el.classList.add("hide");
        }
    
        function hideAll(elements) {
            elements.forEach(hide);
        }
    
        function showCovers(playButton) {
            const cover = playButton.parentElement;
            cover.classList.add("active");
            show(cover);
        }
    
        function coverClickHandler(evt) {
            hideAll(config.containers);
            const cover = evt.currentTarget;
            showCovers(cover);
        }
    
        function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
            playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
                playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
            });
        }
    
        function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
            const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
            cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
        }
    
        function init(selectors) {
            config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
            const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
            addClickToButtons(playButtons);
        }
    
        return {
            addCoverHandler,
            init,
            show
        };
    }());
    
    const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init,
    show
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];
  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    player.playVideo();
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      playerOptions: {
        events: {
          "onReady": onPlayerReady
        },
        host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
        videoId: video.dataset.id
      }
    };
    const playerOptions = Object.assign(defaults.playerOptions, settings);
    players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
  }

  return {
    addPlayer

  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerOptions: {
      height: 600,
      playerVars: {
        controls: 1,
        disablekb: 1,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        rel: 0
      },
      width: 360
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
    function paramInOptions(opts, param) {
      if (settings[param] !== undefined) {
        opts[param] = settings[param];
        delete settings[param];
      }
      return opts;
    }

    const optionParams = ["width", "height", "videoid", "host"];
    const defaultOptions = defaults.playerOptions;
    const preferred = optionParams.reduce(paramInOptions, {});
    const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, preferred);
    // settings should now only consist of playerVars
    const defaultPlayerVars = defaultOptions.playerVars;
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, defaultPlayerVars, settings);
    playerOptions.playerVars = playerVars;
    return playerOptions;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  function init(playerOptions) {
    Object.assign(defaults.playerOptions, playerOptions);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.add("svg.playa", {
    height: 207,
    width: 277
  });
  managePlayer.add("svg.playb", {
    height: 207,
    width: 277
  });
  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the line 140 in your code?

Comment: const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings);

Comment: I clicked on the wrong one, I never used bounty before. I'm not looking for a reputable source. I'm looking for an answer that solves the issue of the delay occuring.

Comment: All I am trying to do is remove the delay, that is all.

Comment: If you are able to solve the bounty you will get the 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the players prior to the click event happening. One possible approach would be to do it in `createCoverClickHandler`.

```js
  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings) {
    // Grap the relevant HTML nodes and create the players early
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.curtain')).forEach(curtain => {
      const player = createPlayer(curtain, playerSettings)

      curtain.player = player
    })

    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
    };
  }
```

You might want to adjust other things based on this change, but this should get the call to `new YT.Player` done before the click event is fired.

Comment: I was not able to get the code working in here. Would you be able to update this jsitor code for me? https://jsitor.com/wHBezLsrz

Comment: You accept the answer given for the code presented in the original question (https://jsitor.com/W0Iu1msGS) and then you can't figure out how to use it with slightly different code (jsitor.com/wHBezLsrz), so you take away your acceptance unless I answer the second question for you? Lol

Comment: I didn't know if I was going to hear back. Sorry about that. I tried adding it to this code and I couldn't get it to work in it. https://jsitor.com/wHBezLsrz

Comment: @buildingcode543 you are funny man. Same link different code. I'm not here for the points man, do what you want with them.